# Laravel 500 HPHP error loading script

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a site with Laravel to do geolocation. I'm new to Laravel, so first wrote the code in PHP to call two external scripts, one from Google's geoloc API and another from my local server to tell the page what to do:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>
<script src="geoloc.js"></script>
```

Then, in the body, I put a div for the map and a button to stop querying Google's server:

```
<body onload="geoloc()">
    <p id = 'mapdiv'></p>
    <button onclick="stopWatch()">
        Stop
    </button>

</body>
```

Everything works fine.

Then I tried to port it over to Laravel. Since this is a front end thing, I wanted to put it in the views, and thought I'd just attach it to the welcome.blade.php view for testing, since I know that one comes up ok. I created a js subfolder in the laravel/public folder, and put the script there. I then used an HTML helper in the header to call up the scripts:

```
{{ HTML::script('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true'); }}
{{ HTML::script('\public\js\geoloc.js'); }}
```

I appended the PHP in the body:

```
<p onload="geoloc()" id = 'mapdiv'></p>
<button onclick="stopWatch()">
    Stop
</button>
```

and get nothing. Debugging shows a GET 500 hphp invoke.

Thoughts?

Comment: If you're using Laravel 5, you should do `{!! ... !!}` instead of `{{ ... }}` to prevent escaping. They changed the syntax from 4 to 5. That could be the cause. Also, shouldn't that be `/js/geoloc.js` rather than `\public\js\geoloc.js`?

Comment: Did you install the HTML module? Unlike Laravel 4, Laravel 5 doesn't include the HTML module required to use the `HTML` facade by default. If you want to use it you'll have to install it using composer. It can be found on packagist [here.](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html)

Comment: Hi, guys. Thanks for answering. I had installed the HTML module and tried  the {!!...!!} syntax. No joy. Still get the white screen of death and the 500 hphp error.